Book about a spaceship that crashed under the surface of a planet
I recall reading a book about a spaceship that crashed and people couldn't get out for a while because it was under the surface they had to dig up. Interestingly, the characters were referred to by their professions (like "the Doctor" or "the Engineer") rather than by names – that's what I clearly remember.
The planet had some kind of advanced civilization, but the astronauts couldn't make sense of it.
There were strange structures and machines that didn't seem to have clear purposes. The aliens there were very different and communication was nearly impossible. They had to kill many aliens while exploring.
The rule on the planet was kinda dystopian and very weird.

Eden by Stanisław Lem?


A six-man crew crash-lands on Eden, fourth planet from another sun. The men find a strange world that grows ever stranger, and everywhere there are images of death. The crew's attempt to communicate with this civilization leads to violence and to a cruel truth—cruel precisely because it is so human.

The ship crashes on the planet Eden and as you say the occupants have to dig their way out. Also as you say all the characters are just referred to by their professions. For example immediately after the crash we have the passage:

"We're alive," said the Chemist. In total darkness, he could not see a thing. He was hanging in his nylon bag fastened on four sides by cords. The ship had to be lying on its side: otherwise the berth would have been horizontal. There was a crackle, and the pale glimmer of the Doctor's old lighter.
"Roll call," said the Captain. A cord on his bag snapped, causing him to rotate slowly, helplessly. He reached out through the nylon netting and tried unsuccessfully to grab a knob on the wall.
"Here," said the Engineer.
"Here," said the Physicist.
"Here," said the Chemist.
"I'm here," said the Cyberneticist, holding his head.
"And here, that's six," said the Doctor.


I thought of that before I even read the body of the question, because at least in the German edition the doctor (I think) almost literally says "we must be the first space ship to crash below the surface of a planet" after they realized the space ship is half buried.

That scene reminds me so much of Disney's Atlantis. "All right, who's not dead? Sound off."

Definitely Eden. Every detail matches. @Groovy, please checkmark.
